# Migrate EMF / GMF based eclipse 3 plugins to RCP

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-gmf

Some time ago I created a graphical editor with GMF ( xsd->ecore->emf->gmf).
Additionally I created plugins with different views, launchers (debugger) and more.

All those plugins were created with Eclipse Helios.

Now, I would like to create a RCP application out of my plugins.
I did a lot of internet research but still do not really understand how to begin.

I read this tutorial (http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseRCP/article.html#plugin_creatinge4) but I am still not sure what to do.
If I would do as told in this tutorial, I would have to build all the windows, editors, menus and so on manually, correct ?

And if so, how to get those default eclipse features in my RCP application, like: Create an empty project, starting my "New Diagram" Wizard, double click the diagram file in the project view to open the editor...and so on...

Do I really have to build all those features manually with the Application Model file ??

I really could use some pointers to the right direction.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The tutorial you have found is describing the new e4 API. This does not support a lot of the older 3.x compatibility APIs so it is not suitable for using to build a RCP which uses plugins based on 3.x. The e4 API is good for building new RCPs which don't use 3.x plugins.

Instead you can still build a 3.x style RCP, see [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Eclipse3RCP/article.html) for more details on doing that. The 3.x style RCP will continue to be supported for a long time.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am still having problems to create a RCP out of my plugins even as 3.x style RCP. At the moment I am staying with the plugin solution and will come back to this topic some other time.